# How to retrieve hashed password from sql database vb.net

Tags: vb.net, hash

I have this code below which coverts my textbox text to a variable characters and numbers.
example: if i type "admin" to textbox1, i will have an output of "751cb3f4aa17c36186f4856c8982bf27".
Now, I wanted to do the reverse. Anyone have any idea?

```
Dim hs As Byte() = New Byte(49) {}
Dim pass As String = textbox1.Text
Dim md5 As MD5 = MD5.Create()
Dim inputBytes As Byte() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(pass)
Dim hash As Byte() = md5.ComputeHash(inputBytes)
Dim sb As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()
    For i As Integer = 0 To hash.Length - 1
        hs(i) = hash(i)
        sb.Append(hs(i).ToString("x2"))
    Next
Dim hash_pass = sb.ToString()
```

Comment: Hashes, such as md5 which you are using are one way hashes, their purpose is when a password is entered by the user, it can be hashed and then the hash can be compared against the one in the database to validate the password. This means if a hacker accesses your database they cannot get any passwords from it.

Comment: thankz for the abrupt answer. At least now i know what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be "reversing" an MD5 Hash. Hashes are meant to be one way only. If you want to be able to reverse the encoded message, you will want to use a cipher such as base64. It is worth noting, ciphers do not give you security as they can be restored to the original input.

[This](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/29234/is-base64-the-best-two-way-hash-function-to-encrypt-and-transmit-a-set-of-intege) answer helps explain the differences and their different use cases.

[Here](https://www.base64encode.net/vb-system-convert-tobase64string) is some documentation on using `System.Convert.ToBase64String()` which can be reversed with `System.Convert.FromBase64String()`